# Why couldn't I start a CouchDB container with the command below?

Tags: docker, couchdb, obsidian

I was trying to implement liveSync plugin for my Obsidian. I've exactly followed the steps introduced by the [official document](https://github.com/vrtmrz/obsidian-livesync/blob/main/docs/setup_own_server.md), but all the efforts stuck here.

Environment: Aliyun ECS

Command:
`docker run --rm -t -e COUCHDB_USER=admin -e COUCHDB_PASSWORD=password -v /home/etc/local.ini:/opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini -p 5984:5984 78991f849f8c`

local.ini:

```
[couchdb]
single_node=true
max_document_size = 50000000

[chttpd]
require_valid_user = true
max_http_request_size = 4294967296

[chttpd_auth]
require_valid_user = true
authentication_redirect = /_utils/session.html

[httpd]
WWW-Authenticate = Basic realm="couchdb"
enable_cors = true

[cors]
origins = app://obsidian.md,capacitor://localhost,http://localhost
credentials = true
headers = accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer
methods = GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE
max_age = 3600
```

Output:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXyC2.jpg)
then it got stuck.